# jQuery text html manipulation to find occurences of a char in a multitude of text then change it's color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, text

I got this `HTML`

```
    <div id="oops_menuHldrs" 
        style=" border-top:5px solid #ccc; position:absolute; width:100%;  background:#343434; bottom:0px; left:auto;">

          <div style="position:absolute; background:#343434; border-radius:10px; border:1px solid #CCC; right:0px; top:-20px;  padding:5px;">


<table id="opps_menu_links"  width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td><span><a href="../?abt=us">About us</a> black_text | black_text</span></td>
        <td><span><a href="../?ourA=gent">Our Agents</a> black_text | black_text</span></td>
        <td><span><a href="../contact=us">Contact us.</a> black_text | black_text </span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>


 </div>
```

Am told to, using `jQuery`, select all `|` and give them color red.

I tried something like:

```
$('#opps_menu_links').html( 
        $('#opps_menu_links').text()
        .replace(/\|/,"<span style='color:#f00;'>|</span>"));
```

This converts everything to a single Red `|`

of course this without `jQuery` would otherwise be easy, just clothing each `|` with `spans`... but how would you do it using `jQuery` with as minimal codes as possible?

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script as below

http://jsfiddle.net/xHasy/

```
$('#opps_menu_links').html($('#opps_menu_links').html( ).replace(/\|/g,'<span style="color:red;">|</span>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct except you forgot to place global match parameter`"g"` in the regex:

```
.replace(/\|/g,
//-----------^----place this
```

final code should be:

```
$('#opps_menu_links').html( 
        $('#opps_menu_links').text()
        .replace(/\|/g,"<span style='color:#f00;'>|</span>"));
    //---------------^----------place here
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C2UD5/)